# Reflecting an exponential function over a y = 3 line.

Tags: functions, transformation, exponential-function, reflection

How would you write the equation of $f(x) = 4^x$ that reflects over the line $y = 3$?

I've put in $f(x) = 3 + 4^{-x}$ which I thought was the right answer, but it isn't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Reflecting around $y=3$ sends $y$ to $6-y$